# What Am I doing wrong in this C program to check a string is Palindrome or not?

Tags: c, palindrome

Following is the C program I wrote to check whether Entered string is Palindrome or not, but it always displays the 'else' statement i.e. The string is not Palindrome:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
int i,n,count=0;
char f[30];
printf("Enter the string. :  ");
gets(f);
n = strlen(f);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(f[i+1]==f[n-i])
    count=count+1;
}
if(count==n)
printf("\n Entered string is Palindrome");
else
printf("\n Entered string is NOT Palindrome");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should use print statements or a debugger to look at the values in `n` and `count`. Compare them with your expected values.

Comment: First of all you should stop using `gets`. [It's a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), and has therefore been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. And your program _is_ really small.

Comment: Are you sure your program *always* displays the 'else' statement? Try one-char input.

Comment: Thank you all for all the answers, count always shows 1.

Comment: @VengenceTech "count always shows 1" really? I tested with an input `ab` and got a result `count = 0` by adding `printf("%d\n", count);` just before `if(count==n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `i = 0`, `f[n-i]` will be the terminating null character, which will never appear in the middle of the string.
Because of that, if the string is 2-char long or more, the condition `f[i+1]==f[n-i]` will be false.
(If the string is 1-char long, `f[i+1]` will be the terminating null character after the first (and only) character, so the condition will be true.)

The condition should be `f[i]==f[n-i-1]`.

By the way,

- You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11.
- You should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use this non-standard signature (for example, forced to use this from your boss or teacher).

An example of full fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,n,count=0;
    char f[30 + 1]; /* allocate one more element for storeing newline character */
    char* lf;
    printf("Enter the string. :  ");
    fgets(f, sizeof(f), stdin); /* change gets() to fgets() */
    /* fgets() stores newline character while gets() doesn't, so remove it */
    if ((lf = strchr(f, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    n = strlen(f);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(f[i]==f[n-i-1])
        count=count+1;
    }
    if(count==n)
        printf("\n Entered string is Palindrome");
    else
        printf("\n Entered string is NOT Palindrome");

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, Here we are forced to use Borland compiler which suggests Education system here is outdated and they dont intend to change.

Answer (score 0):

I think just the indexing in the string is wrong. Change it from i+1 to i and n-i-2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int i,n,count=0;
    char f[30];
    printf("Enter the string. :  ");
    fgets(f, 29, stdin);
    n = strlen(f);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(f[i]==f[n-i-2])
        count=count+1;
    }
    if(count==n)
    printf("\n Entered string is Palindrome");
    else
    printf("\n Entered string is NOT Palindrome");

}
```

Also another more efficient should would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    int i = 0,n,count=0;
    char f[30];
    printf("Enter the string. :  ");
    fgets(f, 29, stdin);
    n = strlen(f);

    while (i < n >> 1) {
        if (f[i]!=f[n-i-2]) {
            printf("\n Entered string is NOT Palindrome\n");
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n Entered string is Palindrome\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", f);` also have risk of buffer overrun. `scanf("%29s", f);` is better. (not `%30s` because a room for terminating null character must be allocated)

Comment: yeah I just changed it for fast prototyping, I will change it :)

Comment: Got it, bro Thank you

Comment: Note that using fgets, the strlen also counts the new line feed, so the palindrome right side starts at n-i-2